# jmespath select first matched attribute

Tags: python, jmespath

I'd like to know if there is a succint way to express `foo.bar||foo.boo` with jmespath

```
>>> import jmespath
>>> jmespath.search("foo.bar||foo.boo", {"foo":{"bar":"a", "boo":"b"}})
'a'
>>> jmespath.search("foo.[bar||boo]", {"foo":{"bar":"a", "boo":"b"}})
['a']
>>> jmespath.search("foo.[bar||boo][0]", {"foo":{"bar":"a", "boo":"b"}})
'a'
```

Is there a way to express the path as `foo.(bar||boo)` leading to the desired (`scalar` not `array`) result `'a'` ?

Edit :

It seems to work using `|` instead of `.`

```
>>> jmespath.search("foo|bar||boo", {"foo":{"bar":"a", "boo":"b"}}) 
'a'
```

Comment: What happens when you use `foo.(bar||boo)`?

Comment: `jmespath.exceptions.ParseError: Expecting: ['quoted_identifier', 'unquoted_identifier', 'lbracket', 'lbrace'], got: lparen: Parse error at column 4, token "(" (LPAREN), for expression: "foo.(bar||boo)"`